# Is there an event when user types a subject?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I want to autofill a subject based on what the user types in to the subject field of an email.  For example, the user starts typing T201234567 and the program will fill in the rest.

T201234567 SR9&54 Project title

I found the event for when a new email is created, but I would ideally like to have this program be as unobtrusive as possible, so it would only suggest titles, as the user is typing in something it recognizes.

So, is there an onKeyPress event for the subject field?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such event. `PropertyChange ("Subject")` event will fire only when the user tabs out of the Subject edit box.

You can find the control's handle using Win API and intercept its Windows messages, but you cannot do that in VBA.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks anyway.  I think i'm going to try to tie it to Crtl+Space